# HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, servlets, jena

I have created a web project in eclipse and in order to run the project in Tomcat server i had exported the file in .war format. I have kept a separate computer to run the project, so i could use it from different computers as it has a static IP.

My current error is:

> HTTP Status 500 - Error instantiating servlet class com.complexible.common.csv.DisplayRecord

I am adding my web.xml file. Please provide me the possible solutions.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
- <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Museumnew</display-name> 
- <welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file> 
  <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file> 
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file> 
  <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file> 
  <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file> 
  <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file> 
  <welcome-file>/axis2-web/index.jsp</welcome-file> 
  </welcome-file-list>
- <servlet>
  <description /> 
  <display-name>DisplayRecord</display-name> 
  <servlet-name>DisplayRecord</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>com.complexible.common.csv.DisplayRecord</servlet-class> 
  </servlet>
- <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>DisplayRecord</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/DisplayRecord</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
- <servlet>
  <display-name>Apache-Axis Servlet</display-name> 
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AxisServlet</servlet-class> 
  </servlet>
- <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/servlet/AxisServlet</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
- <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>*.jws</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
- <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
- <servlet>
  <display-name>Axis Admin Servlet</display-name> 
  <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis.transport.http.AdminServlet</servlet-class> 
  <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>
- <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AdminServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/servlet/AdminServlet</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
- <servlet>
  <display-name>Apache-Axis Admin Servlet Web Admin</display-name> 
  <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name> 
  <servlet-class>org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisAdminServlet</servlet-class> 
  <load-on-startup>100</load-on-startup> 
  </servlet>
- <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>AxisAdminServlet</servlet-name> 
  <url-pattern>/axis2-admin/*</url-pattern> 
  </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

Here is a servlet code.

```
package com.complexible.common.csv;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class DisplayRecord
 */
public class DisplayRecord extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @throws IOException 
     * @throws ParseException 
     * @throws JSONException 
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public DisplayRecord() throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {
        super();

        String  getrec=GetRecord.getrec("http://phdprototype.tk/collectionimage/4D0BFF17-5810-4644-A550-D35EE090D4A8.png","3","0");
        System.out.println(getrec);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PrintWriter out= response.getWriter();
                //out.print("hesadlo");

                String abc="";

                try {
                    abc = GetRecord.getrec("http://phdprototype.tk/collectionimage/4D0BFF17-5810-4644-A550-D35EE090D4A8.png","3","0");
                } catch (JSONException | ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                out.print(abc);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us your servlet code.

Comment: Look at your server logfile what happends.

Comment: ...plus the error-message from the server-log that show the exception...

Comment: I bet `DisplayRecord` doesn't extend `HttpServlet`

Answer (score -1):

I think this error your getting because you are not **made your servlet class as public**. The object of your servlet class should be visible to the container because container creating object for your servlet class.

Comment: This should be a comment not an answer.

Answer (score -2):

Thank you for the replies, when i checked a log file, i got to know that the path of one of the file was wrong and i fixed that. Now it is working properly.

Comment: where is the log file generated?